# Combining SAS Data Sets with different no. of columns

Tags: sas

I am having problem in combining two tables with different no. of columns.

Say my first table is **table1**:

```
table1
t1_col_1   t1_col_2   t1_col_3  ...  t1_col_13
```

and my second table is **table2**:

```
table2
 t2_col_1   t2_col2   t2_col3   t2_col4
```

Now if I type command:

```
                 data table3;
                 set tabel1 table2;
                 run;
```

What will be the out put of table3 ?

The SAS link says this command do a concatanation:
 http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001107839.htm

Since the columns no. are different, concatenation will cause problem.

So how does this command exactly works ? And what will be its output in this case ?

Comment: Mukesh, can you explain what you want to achieve?  You did not really describe exactly what you want to make happen.

Comment: @John as you can see there are two tables with different column no.
Now if I type the above command **data table3...** how will it work on this, basically how the output will look like on table3 ?

Answer (score 1):

Appending (concatenating) two or more data sets is basically just stacking the data sets together with values in variables of the same name being stacked together. Unique variables in each data set will form their own variables in the new combined data set. Right now we have different number of variables. This article explains how concatenation works between data sets with different variables: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/basess/58133/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001312944.htm

For example, suppose we have:

```
data work.table1;
input col1 $ col2 col3 col4;
datalines;
George 10 10 10  
Lucy 10 10 10 
;
run;
data work.table2;
input col1 $ col2;
datalines;
Shane 3
Peter 3
;
run;

data work.table3;
    set table1 table2;
run;
```

OUTPUT:

```
                           col1     col2    col3    col4

                          George     10      10      10
                          Lucy       10      10      10
                          Peter       3       .       .  <== These entries are
                          Shane       3       .       .       empty.
```

col1 and col2 are present in both sets, so the values inside them will be stacked. col3 and col4 are only present in table1, so some of the values under them in the new combined set will be empty.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But this is my requirement I can't use merge.

Comment: Ok I've changed my method to concatenate. Since I can't see your date sets I assume concatenating is what you're asked to do.